# Django annotate queryset with intersection count

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Djangonauts, I need to tap your brains.

In a nutshell, I have the following three models:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Profile(models.Model):
    locations_of_interest = models.ManyToManyField(Location)


class Question(models.Model):
    locations = models.ManyToManyField(Location)
```

I want to find all Profiles which locations of interest intersect with the locations specified for a certain question. That’s easy:

```
question = Question.objects.first()

matching_profiles = Profile.objects.filter(
    locations_of_interest__in=question.locations.all()
)
```

But in addition, I would also like to know to what extend the locations overlap.

In plain python, I could do something like this:

```
question_location_names = [l['name'] for l in question.locations.all()]

for profile in matching_profiles:
    profile_location_names = [l['name'] for l in profile.locations_of_interest.all()]
    intersection = set(question_location_names).intersection(profile_location_names)
    intersection_count = len(list(intersection))
    # then proceed with this number
```

However, it seems to me favourable to do the operation directly in the database if possible.

**TL;DR**

So my question is:

Is there a way to annotate the profile queryset with this intersection count and that way do the operation in the database?

I have tried several things, but I don’t think they are helpful for those who read this and might know an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform this with an `.annotate(..)` this with a `Count(..)` on the `locations_of_interest` number:

```
from django.db.models import Count

matching_profiles = Profile.objects.filter(
    locations_of_interest__in=question.locations.all()
).annotate(
    locnom=Count('locations_of_interest')
)
```

Now every `matching_profiles` instance, will have an attribute called `locnom` that contains the number of location of interests that matched with the filter.

Note that `Profile`s without such locations, will not be in the queryset, and that every `Profile` will occur at most once.

**EDIT**: counting multiple related non-overlapping (!) fields

You can extend this approach by counting non-overlapping joins, by using `distinct=True`:

```
from django.db.models import Count

matching_profiles = Profile.objects.filter(
    locations_of_interest__in=question.locations.all(),
    industries_of_interest__in=question.industries.all()
).annotate(
    locnom=Count('locations_of_interest', distinct=True),
    indnom=Count('industries_of_interest', distinct=True)
)
```

Note however that this approach scales typically then *exponentially* with the number of `JOIN`s, so this is typically *not* scalable if you would add tens our hundreds of annotations.

Comment: This works indeed, thanks. What does not seem to work, however, is to pull the same trick with a second attribute, say `industries_of_interest` on `Profile` and `industries` on `Question`, at the same time. Is that right to your knowledge?

Comment: @creimers: I think you can solve this by using `distinct=True` in the count. (on both `Count`s.

Comment: ding dong. Now I'm all set. Will not add more than these two annotations. Dankjewel.

Comment: Any way to do this without the filtering? What if I still want to show all profiles, even if they're not in the question locations, but still annotate by the intersection of locations so that I can sort on the count of intersection? Would that have to be two queries chained together?

Comment: edit: made it it's own question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51504634/django-intersect-count-annotate-for-sorting

Comment: @dster77: So if I understand it correctly, you want to include `Profile`s as well with no intersecting `locations_of_interest`, and `industries_of_interest` as well, that is the only difference? (in that case `locnum`, etc. will be `0`).