# Django intersect count annotate for sorting

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555817/django-annotate-queryset-with-intersection-count), we were given a solution to sort a query based on the intersection of two many to many fields. While it's a great answer, the restriction is that you have to filter first.

Say I have the same two models. Is there a way to annotate all results by count of intersection, so that I can display all Questions regardless of location, but still sorted by location?

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Profile(models.Model):
    locations_of_interest = models.ManyToManyField(Location)


class Question(models.Model):
    locations = models.ManyToManyField(Location)
```

I wish I could do something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count

matching_profiles = Profile.objects.all().annotate(
    locnom=Count('locations_of_interest__in=question.locations.all()')
)
```

Any ideas? Do I just have to make two queries and merge them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can move the filtering in the `Count` function as well:

```
Profile.objects.annotate(
    locnom=Count('id', filter=Q(locations_of_interest__in=question.locations.all()))
)
```

The two are *not* equivalent in the sense that `Profile`s with *no* related `Location`s, or in case the `question` has no location, will still be included, in that case the `.locnom` of that `Profile` will be `0`.

The query looks approximately like:

```
SELECT profile.*,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN proloc.location_id IN (1, 4, 5) THEN profile.id ELSE NULL)
           AS locnom
FROM profile
LEFT OUTER JOIN profile_locations_of_interest AS proloc
             ON profile.id = proloc.profile_id
GROUP BY profile.id
```

Where `[1, 4, 5]` are here *sample* `id`s of the related `Location`s of the `question`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use subquery https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Like this example: https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/subquery.html

```
from django.db.models import Subquery
users = User.objects.all()
UserParent.objects.filter(user_id__in=Subquery(users.values('id')))
```